Elasticsearch aggregation get a list of all values taken by a specific field
Each of my elasticrecords I'm searching contain a "status" field that contains an http status code,
I made this request to get the average of the api-response-time on a defined time range by uri  :
GET /gravitee-*/_search
{
  "query": { 
    "bool": { 
      
      "filter": [ 
        { "range": { "@timestamp": { "gte": "now-50d/d" }}}
      ]
    }
  },
    "aggs": {
      "average_api-response-time": {
        "terms": {
            "field" : "uri"
            },
        "avg": { "field" : "api-response-time" }
      }
    }
}

I wish to also get all the values that the "status" field took during this timerange ( it contains numericals : 200,401,etc.. ).
Is it possible without an histogram request ?
Thanks for helping !
Edit :
Solved on reddit thanks to u/do-u-even-search-bro :
 GET /gravitee-*/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "@timestamp": {
        "gte": "now-50d/d"
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_uri": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "uri"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "average_response_time": {
          "avg": {
            "field": "api-response-time"
          }
        },
        "status_terms": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "status"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

